# Changing group ownership of files - User management

Tags: users, non-root-user, syslog-ng

Installed an application as `root` owner but not as non-root. why? Because we had to install this application in custom location(`/app`)

So, after installing an application(Syslog-NG), below are the files with current ownership:

```
# ls -l /app/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 938 Aug 20 12:43 /app/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng.conf
# ls -l /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39768 Aug 20 12:43 /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng
```

---

Requirement is to have a new local user(non root) on this RHEL server,

```
# uname -a
Linux abc123.xy.ef.com 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 14 10:36:03 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

which can read/modify file(`syslog-ng.conf`) and execute file(`syslog-ng`)

**Goal** - Application should not need elevated privileges to run. This new username is suppose to belong to that application but not to any specific user. This new username cannot be in `/etc/sudoers` for elevated privilege. Every LDAP user(employee) logging into that machine will sudo to this new username, before working with that application.

---

1) Do I need to create a new group(say `newgrp`) with some permissions?  Command syntax please..

If yes...

2) What is the command syntax to add new user to be part of that group? `chgrp newgrp filename` would suffice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new user and a new group:

```
sudo adduser foo
```

Then, change the group of the file:

```
sudo chgrp foo /app/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng.conf
```

And add the write permission:

```
sudo chmod 664 /app/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng.conf
```

Executing /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng should, according to the permissions, be already possible for every user.

Comment: How to add new user into `foo`?

Comment: @overexchange I used "foo" as an example. It's the name of the created user, aswell as the group. If you want to add an existing user to the group, do "adduser <username> foo"

Comment: Can I maintain one name for both username and groupname?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Every user has its own group, named after the user. I suggest you read up on this topic:https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/12659-understanding-linux-users-and-groups

Comment: This was nice article..for me.... as a newbie to user management & Linux admin stuff....

Comment: As a root user, am running `useradd` commands... you did not mention in the answer... How an LDAP user(employee) logged into machine would then switch to this new local user? Does LDAP user need to run `su foo` and provide `foo`'s password?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, that is correct.